# Android Debugging: Error accessing memory address

Tags: android, research, debugging

I'm attempting to debug different native binaries in my Android device using the adb shell and gdbserver.

I receive the following error when i place a breakpoint in a program using gdb and continue the program's run:

**Error accessing memory address : Input/output error**

I'm using a rooted device and i'm operating through the root user.

What can be the possible reasons for this error?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can help with so little information to go on